# Successfully installed amazon-efs-utils but cannot find it

Tags: filesystems, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

```
$ sudo yum install -y amazon-efs-utils --verbose
Loading "extras_suggestions" plugin
Loading "langpacks" plugin
Loading "priorities" plugin
Loading "update-mood" plugin
Adding en_US to language list
Config time: 0.391
Yum version: 3.4.3
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Package Sacks
amzn2-core
pkgsack time: 0.052
Obs Init time: 0.172
Package amazon-efs-utils-1.29.1-1.amzn2.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Installation of `amazon-efs-utils` seems to be successful as shown above.

But when I try to run the tool, I get this error:

```
$ sudo amazon-efs-utils
sudo: amazon-efs-utils: command not found
```

1. Is it possible that the URL from where `amazon-efs-utils` gets downloaded is blocked and hence it did not really get downloaded?
2. I ran `yum` with `--verbose` option to see if it would print a trace of which URL it tries to download the tool from. But it did not! Any idea how I can find which URL `amazon-efs-utils` would be downloaded from so that I can try whitelisting that URL on my server and try again?

I am using Amazon Linux2 EC2 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Ask rpm if the package is installed.

```
$ rpm -qa|grep amazon-efs-utils
```

If it is, check its contents.

```
$ rpm -ql amazon-efs-utils
```

Observe the package contents files.
Also, understand that amazon-efs-utils adds some binaries prefixed by mount.
Here is the output in an ec2 instance.

```
$ rpm -ql amazon-efs-utils.noarch
/etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.conf
/etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.crt
/sbin/mount.efs
/usr/bin/amazon-efs-mount-watchdog
/usr/lib/systemd/system/amazon-efs-mount-watchdog.service
/usr/share/man/man8/mount.efs.8.gz
/var/log/amazon
/var/log/amazon/efs
```

Check the [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/using-amazon-efs-utils.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the efs-utils is installed via following commands

```
mount.efs --version
```

And you can check the command line tool detail via

```
man mount.efs
```